# How to find a multiline match with RegEx in a text file using VBA?

Tags: regex, vba

I have a .txt report that I need to extract certain elements (using RegEx groups) that occur multiple times throughout the file.  In order to capture the specific elements I need, I have to match the text in a textline against a pattern then look ahead to see if the next line matches a different pattern.  If both are true, then return values of those groups into an array.

I am working in Excel 2013 using VBA and the RegExp library.  I was able to write a multiline pattern in RegEx along with all the relevant fields I need in named groups.  I am able to open a text file and load the data to a string.  What I can't do is both at the same time.  I've only been able to identify one line of text against one pattern.

Edit: Here is some sample text that has been redacted from the original source

> ```
>                                                      DAILY CONTROL REPORT                                    WORK OF: 08/07/19  
>                                                      ACQUIRING                                                     PAGE:    1   
> CUSTOMER           : ACME CORP                                                                                                      
> CUSTOMER ID        : 0000000001                                                                                                     
> Other miscellaneous data
>
>                                                      DAILY CONTROL REPORT                                    WORK OF: 08/07/19  
>                                                      ISSUING                                                       PAGE:    2   
> CUSTOMER           : ACME CORP                                                                                                      
> CUSTOMER ID        : 0000000001                                                                                                     
> Other miscellaneous data
>
>                                                      DAILY CONTROL REPORT                                    WORK OF: 08/07/19  
>                                                      NET SETTLEMENT SUMMARY                                        PAGE:    3   
> CUSTOMER           : ACME CORP                                                                                                      
> CUSTOMER ID        : 0000000001                                                                                                     
> Other miscellaneous data
>
>                                                      DAILY CONTROL REPORT                                    WORK OF: 08/07/19  
>                                                      ACQUIRING                                                     PAGE:    4   
> CUSTOMER           : ACME INC                                                                                                       
> CUSTOMER ID        : 0000000002                                                                                                     
> Other miscellaneous data
>
>                                                      DAILY CONTROL REPORT                                    WORK OF: 08/07/19  
>                                                      ISSUING                                                       PAGE:    5   
> CUSTOMER           : ACME INC                                                                                                       
> CUSTOMER ID        : 0000000002                                                                                                     
> Other miscellaneous data
>
>                                                      DAILY CONTROL REPORT                                    WORK OF: 08/07/19  
>                                                      NET SETTLEMENT SUMMARY                                        PAGE:    6   
> CUSTOMER           : ACME INC                                                                                                       
> CUSTOMER ID        : 0000000002                                                                                                     
> Other miscellaneous data
> ```

```
Dim rgx As Object
Set rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim TextLine As String
Dim strPattern As String
Dim strReport As String
Dim MyArray() As Variant
Dim i As Integer

MyFolder = "C:\Reports\Samples\"
MyFile = "MySampleFile.txt"
strPattern = "WORK OF: (?<WORKOF>\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d)\s+\n\s+NET SETTLEMENT 
SUMMARY.+\n.{22}(?<NAME>.+\b)\s+\n.{22}(?<NUM>\d+)\s+\n"

With rgx
.Global = True
.MultiLine = True
.IgnoreCase = False
.Pattern = strPattern
End With

Open (MyFolder & MyFile) For Input As #1
Do Until EOF(1)
Line Input #1, TextLine
strReport = strReport & TextLine
Loop
Close #1

i = 0

If rgx.Test(strReport) Then
ReDim Preserve MyArray(0 to i, 0 to 2)
MyArray(i, 0) = rgx.Replace(strReport, WORKOF)  
MyArray(i, 1) = rgx.Replace(strReport, NAME)    
MyArray(i, 2) = rgx.Replace(strReport, NUM) 
i = i +1
End IF
```

There are a few things I know are wrong with this code:
  1. The strReport string does not include CrLF at end of each line
  2. The rgx.Test statement should loop through strReport looking for a 
     multiline match but the way it is written, it would always fail the test.
  3. I am not sure how the array would be populated but it would end up with several hundred records, each with 3 values {WORKOF, NAME, NUM}
  4. WORKOF is in the header of every page but the string "NET SETTLEMENT SUMMARY" only occurs about every 3rd or 4th page.  That is where the information I want to capture resides.

Comment: We'll need to see data from your `MySampleFile.txt` in order to evaluate what your regex is doing. Plus include what exact results you want from the regex, given the sample data.

Comment: When you read the file you're essentially stripping out the line separators - add them in when you build up strReport.  Or don't read line-by-line:  http://codevba.com/office/read_text_file_into_string_variable.htm   And at least on Windows the line separator is typically vbCRLf (\r\n)

Comment: I didn't know VBA supported named groups.

Comment: Actually, VBA regex engine ***doesn't*** support named capturing groups. Just checked in MS Excel 2013. And the *2. The rgx.Test statement should loop through strReport looking for a multiline match but the way it is written, it would always fail the test.* proves it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your text files but I created a test input file with the following content:

> WORK OF: 12/34/56 NET SETTLEMENT SUMMARY name1 789
>
> WORK OF: 01/23/45 NET SETTLEMENT SUMMARY name1 6789

I could match the pattern with the following code:

```
Option Explicit

' Include: Tools > References > Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5

Public Sub FindPatternInTextFile_Test()
    Dim varResult As Variant: varResult = FindPatternInTextFile("C:\Reports\Samples\MySampleFile.txt", "WORK OF: (\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d)\s+NET SETTLEMENT SUMMARY\s+(.+\b)\s+(\d+)")
End Sub

Public Function FindPatternInTextFile(strPath As String, strPattern As String) As Variant
    Dim strContent As String: strContent = ReadWholeTextFile(strPath)
    Dim rgxPattern As RegExp: Set rgxPattern = CreateRegex(strPattern)
    Dim mtcFound As MatchCollection: Set mtcFound = rgxPattern.Execute(strContent)
    If 0 < mtcFound.Count Then
        Dim strResult() As String: ReDim strResult(0 To mtcFound.Count - 1, 0 To 2)
        Dim i As Long: For i = 0 To mtcFound.Count - 1
            strResult(i, 0) = mtcFound(i).SubMatches(0)
            strResult(i, 1) = mtcFound(i).SubMatches(1)
            strResult(i, 2) = mtcFound(i).SubMatches(2)
        Next i
        FindPatternInTextFile = strResult
    Else
        FindPatternInTextFile = vbNullString
    End If
End Function

Public Function ReadWholeTextFile(strPath As String) As String
    Dim strResult As String: strResult = vbNullString
    Open strPath For Input As #1
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Dim strLine As String: strLine = vbNullString
        Line Input #1, strLine
        strResult = strResult & strLine & vbCrLf
    Loop
    Close #1
    ReadWholeTextFile = strResult
End Function

Public Function CreateRegex(strPattern As String) As RegExp
    Dim rgxResult As RegExp: Set rgxResult = New RegExp
    With rgxResult
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = strPattern
    End With
    Set CreateRegex = rgxResult
End Function
```

You will have to customize the regex pattern based on your actual data.